# Qiskit Controlled Reset of a qubit

Tags: qiskit

In Qiskit, is there a way to perform a reset of a qubit with control on another without using an additional ancilla qubit?

Comment: could you explain a bit better what you mean? It seems to me like perhaps the answer to your question is a CNOT gate...

Comment: @Lior: No, the CNOT negates, while reset changes any state to $|0\rangle$.

Answer (score 1):

No , From the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.Reset.html) you can only reset based on a classical bit

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please note that once you have enough reputation, you should post such short answers (or link-only answer) as comments.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not 100% sure I understand the context, but I’ll try to answer to the best of my understanding of the question:

If you want to reset a qubit using quantum operations only, you can swap the state with an ancilla in the 0 state. If you want to do it controlled on the state of another qubit, do a controlled swap between the 0 state ancilla and your target qubit with the control qubit as, well, control.

Answer (score 1):

You could perform a hand-rolled conditional reset with something like the code below. This will reset the second qubit if the first qubit is excited.

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit

qreg_q = QuantumRegister(2, 'q')
creg_cw = ClassicalRegister(1, 'cw')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q, creg_cw)


circuit.measure(qreg_q[0], creg_cw[0])
circuit.reset(qreg_q[1]).c_if(creg_cw, 1)
```